# If $\gcd(a, c) = 1$ and $b | c$, prove that $(a, b) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd(a, c)  = 1$ and $b \mid c$, prove that $(a, b) = 1$

-Not sure how to approach this problem.

-We have just started the greatest common divisor section, and looking at my notes I see that $(a \mid c = 1) \implies ax+by = 1$, would this be useful?

-My train of thought is $b \mid c$ then this proof would be relatively straight forward since $c$ is a multiple of $b$.

-I'm struggling with how I would set this up as a proof, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $\gcd(a, c) = 1 \implies ax + cy = 1$?

Comment: yes: updated accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $a$ and $b$. We derive a contradiction. Since $b \mid c$, also $p \mid c$. But then $p$ divides both $a$ and $c$, contradicting gcd$(a,c)=1$.

Comment: Why by contradiction? Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$; then $d\mid b$, so $d\mid c$. On the other hand $d\mid a$. Therefore $d=1$.

Answer (score 1):

"My train of thought is b∣c then this proof would be relatively straight forward since c is a multiple of b".

That's a good thought.  $\gcd(a,b)|a$ and $\gcd(a,b)|b$.  Therefore $\gcd(a,b)|c$.  So $\gcd(a,b)|a$ and $\gcd(a,b)|c$ so $\gcd(a,b)|\gcd(a,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct proof: if $b\mid c$, then $c=bk$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

If $\gcd(a,c)=1$, then by [Bézout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) $ax+cy=1$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

Therefore $a(x)+b(ky)=1$, and $\gcd(a,b)\mid a(x)+b(ky)=1$, so $\gcd(a,b)=1$.